# Using Motion Values to get the clientX position through eventlisteners in Framer motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to get the clientX and clientY and update those into motion Values instead of using useState which causes alot of value updates but it does not seem to work.

```
const First = () => {
  const mouseX = useMotionValue(0);
  const mouseY = useMotionValue(0);

  // const mouseXX = useTransform(mouseX, (v) => v);
  // const mouseYY = useTransform(mouseY, (v) => v)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouse = (e) => {
      mouseX.set(e.clientX);
      mouseY.set(e.clientY);
    };

    const first = mouseX.on("change", handleMouse);
    const second = mouseY.on("change", handleMouse);

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
      handleMouse(e);
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

    return () => {
      first();
      second();
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [mouseX, mouseY]);

  return (
    <motion.div className="text-6xl w-full h-screen bg-blue-300">
      <motion.div
        animate={{
          x: mouseX.current,
          y: mouseY.current,
          transition: {
            duration: 0.1,
          },
        }}
        className="rounded-full w-4 h-4 bg-black"
      ></motion.div>
      {/* <ParallaxText baseVelocity={40}> Hellooooo</ParallaxText> */}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default First;
```

It keeps giving error that e is undefined.i have tried using useTransform to subscribe to the latest changes in motion value which on console.log provide accurate values but for some reason do not work when using it inside the animate.